# Symfony2 from subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I have been working on a `Symfony2` site that lives in a `sub-directory` on `my host`.

```
http_public\
         subfolder\
         oldsite\
```

I have been using `domain.com.au\subfolder\web\` to access the site.

I am trying to make it so that I can access it from `domain.com.au`

I have used the below code in my `.htaccess` which sits in my root folder to rewrite/redirect the flow.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com.au$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/web/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com.au$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/web/index.php [L]
```

This is succeeding in redirecting the base domain `domain.com.au` to the `symfony` site.

All the links to other pages are going to the old site that lives in the sub-directory.

eg. `domain.com.au/link1` is showing the site from the old site that sits in the root-dir.

The htaccess in my `domain.com.au/subfolder/web/` hasn't been changed:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

So I believe that I might need to modify one of these files and maybe some `Symfony` files. I just haven't been able to work out what or where.